# Does "in particular" have the meaning of "for example"?

Tags: meaning

I have seen many textbooks and scientific literatures at least at college level, frequently using "in particular".

I was wondering whether it (always) has the meaning of "for example"?  If yes, does it have other meaning besides that and what differences do they have?

Comment: A closer equivalent to [in particular](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_particular) used this way might be "specifically" or "especially." If someone says, "Unicorns, in particular, pink and purple unicorns, tend to be invisible to the casual observer," you might see these as examples; however, they are given because the speaker or writer wants you to know that pink and purple unicorns are especially likely to be the invisible ones.

Comment: @aediaλ: Firstly, this is a perfectly good answer -- it shouldn't be a comment.  Secondly, why would you use *pink and purple* together with *invisible* ?   Colours are incompatible with invisibility, or, at the very least, it creates a confusing example.  Change the example and make it an answer.

Comment: I disagree with the closevotes. Per Will's answer, things may not always be as simple as mustafa says (though overall I for one think if there must be a single "best" answer, mustafa's should by rights be the most upvoted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For example* gives instances of the thing being discussed.

*In particular* restricts attention of the thing to *specific* instances, but can also mean *especially*. In mathematical texts, this is usually used in the former sense.

Comment: I disagree that the primary significance of *in particular* is to *"restrict attention to to a specific instance"*. More importantly, as @mustafa said several hours earlier, it conveys that the specific thing cited exemplifies whatever is being spoken of *more than any other examples*.

Comment: I think I can just about see what you're getting at. I assume you mean that in *scientific literature* it's more likely that the text may continue by devoting extended consideration to the particular example chosen - not necessarily because it's the most exemplary case, but simply because some greater level of detail will be required to expound on whatever point is being made, and this can only be done by focussing on a single example. Downvote reversed, but overall I'm still sticking with @mustafa's answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the OP talks about textbooks and scientific literature. The sense of restricting the attention is the one I know of.

Comment: @Theta30: As Will says, *in particular* can mean either *specifically* (this is the example we're going to expand on, but the choice of example may have no other significance), or it can mean *especially* (this example is being explicitly identified as an archetypal or extreme instance). It's quite possible the first meaning actually *is* more likely in textbooks. But the expression is commonplace in more general contexts such as Mustafa's example, where I'm in no doubt that the second meaning is usually what's intended.

Answer (score 5):

*In particular* is used to say "more than others". E.g:

> I like reading books. For example; science fiction books, fantasy
>   books, and horror books but I like horror books in particular.

Comment: Agreed, *"more than others"* is the key difference between an instance cited *"for example"* as opposed to *"in particular"*.

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

"**In particular**" is seen as the opposite of "**In general**". This is usually synonymous to "*especially*".

**For example** means *As an example of...*, this is synonymous to "*For instance*", "*e.g*" and "*Such as*".

Though "**In particular**" and "**For example**" may be used in similar cases, note that they do **not** have the same meaning. They may in some cases mean the same thing, but not **always**.

### Cases with Different Meaning

> The chancellor talked about the curriculum, the core courses in particular.

And

> The orchestra was outstanding, the strings in particular

Here "in particular" cannot be replaced with "for example".

> I can play quite a few musical instruments, for example, the flute, the guitar, and the piano.

Using "In particular" over here may change the meaning of the phrase. Using "In particular" may imply that the person is *especially* good at playing the flute, the guitar and the piano. Which may not necessarily be the case.

### Cases with Similar Meaning

> The book has quite a few plot holes. For example, it's never explained why the main character came to town to begin with.

Here "For example" may safely be replaced by "In particular".

Comment: I disagree with your plot example. "in particular" stresses the primary importance of the item given. "For example" does no such thing, allowing unmentioned items to be of even greater importance.